# Request validation on path in Api Gateway

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-api-gateway, aws-serverless

> I have an API gateway which is a kind of url shortner, it accepts all
> the get requests and return the long url associated with that short
> url path. example

input GET => xxx.com/abc

return => aaa.com/blablablabla

> I want to implement some validation on this so that I don't get
> unnecessary junk requests based on path with a regular expression

suppose path should start with "a" in incoming request xxx.com/abc

How can I do that via api gateway request validator, any help

Answer (score 0):

You better try **Lambda Authorizer** for requests validator.

Your Lambda function will have 2 main tasks

- Validate the URL of the request.
- Validate the request's Auth header.

Lambda supports various of languages: Python3, Go, Java, Node.js ... so you are freely to use ReGex to filter your requests.

Reference: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/configure-api-gateway-lambda-authorization-with-console.html

Comment: Have worked on lambda authorizer previously, these url's doesn't need any auth header so was asking if it can be done via api gateway request validator